# If I work for a company and present an Idea and they reject it, can I go on my own and patent that idea?

Tags: patentability, product

I had an idea for a product a couple years ago and I worked on the product at home then I presented it to my employer. They were not really interested, I have now made some modifications and have a better product. What I really want to do is patent it myself. Would they be able to claim it? I signed some paperwork saying that anything discussed at work is there property.

Comment: Have you reviewed your employment contract with them? It will typically say something along the lines of "we own the rights to anything related to your work that you do." But it would be good for us to hear some summary of that clause in yours.

Comment: please improve question by clarifying whether your product was related to company core business and your Job Description?